# EXTJS 4 RemoteSort :True, is not working for Grid.Not getting SORT information on server side

Tags: c#, sorting, extjs

I'm binding only 250 records to  EXT grid, out of 50k records from SQLdb.My Intention was when I wanted to do a sort( not just in store) by clicking on the grid column headers,I supposed to get the  columnName and Direction as part of URL (jsonRequest) in server side,which I can send to my Select statement "orderby" field and get the sorted result. Unfortunately,I'm not getting those sort parameters as part of my URL. just getting url as **dbaccess.aspx/GetUnresolvedChecks?_dc55565656587**
I choose remortSort:true in my store settings, but no luck yet.DO I need to use another proxy?

Do I need to do any change in my PROXY settings or any code change in my server side code?

// Store details

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('ActivityLogDM', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields:  ['AccountClaimNumber', 'CheckNumber', 'Amount', 'ReceivedDate', 'ClaimId', 'AccountNumber', 'StrCreatedDate']
        });

        ActivityLogResult = new Ext.data.Store({
            storeId: 'ActivityLogResult',
            remoteSort: true,
            proxy: new Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy({

                actionMethods: {
                    read: 'POST'
                },
                simpleSortMode: true,
                sorters: [{
                    property: 'CheckNumber',
                    direction: 'ASC'
                }],

                sortParam:'sort',
                url: '../dbaccess.aspx/GetUnresolvedChecks',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    model: 'ActivityLogDM',
                    root: 'd'
                },
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
            }),
            listeners: {
                scope: this,

                load: function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {

                    if (successful) {

                        if (records.length > 0) {
                            ActivityLogResultGrid.getSelectionModel().select(0, true);
                            SelectedClaim = records[0].data;
                            AccountNumber = SelectedClaim.AccountNumber;
                            myClaimID = SelectedClaim.ClaimId;
                        } else {
                            $('#MsgTble').show();
                            $('#btnOK').attr('disabled', true);

                        }

                    }

                },
                loadexception: function(proxy, options, response) {

                },
                dataChanged: function(store) {
                }
            }
        });

        SetActivityLogResultGrid();// seperate function to bind to grid fields
        Ext.getStore('ActivityLogResult').load();
    });
```

// server side code in c#

```
     [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json,
       UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public static List<UnresolvedChecks> GetUnresolvedChecks()
    {

       // string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
        // need to extract the sort parameters from URL and send it to db.
        List<UnresolvedChecks> list = new List<UnresolvedChecks>();
        try
        {
            list = new ReceivedPropertyClaimCheckDAL().GetUnresolvedChecks();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogDAL.LogException(ex);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

//  'Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy.js
      //

```
   Ext.define('Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
   require: 'Ext.data',
   buildRequest: function (operation) {
   var params = Ext.applyIf(operation.params || {}, this.extraParams || {}),
                        request;
   params = Ext.applyIf(params, this.getParams(params, operation));
   if (operation.id && !params.id) {
    params.id = operation.id;
  }
  params = Ext.JSON.encode(params);
  request = Ext.create('Ext.data.Request', {
    params: params,
    action: operation.action,
    records: operation.records,
    operation: operation,
    url: operation.url
});
request.url = this.buildUrl(request);
operation.request = request;
return request;
}
});
```

Comment: `Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy` is not part of the framework. Where did you get it?

Comment: It is also an open source. I have a reference to this .Js library also to my page.It is working perfectly for loading data to store.

Comment: Can some experts help on this issue or suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another proxy server, which is part of framework.It worked